# Best way to copy C++ vector to another with conversion

Tags: c++

What is the best way to copy one vector to another using conversion while coping?
I have following code:

```
vector<Type2> function1(const vector<Type1>& type1Vector) 
{
    vector<Type2> type2Vector(type1Vector.size());
    for (vector<Type1>::const_iterator it = type1Vector.begin(); it < type1Vector.end(); it++) {
        type2Vector.push_back(convertion(*it));
    }

    return type2Vector;
}
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code actually contains a bug, since `type2Vector` will be double the size of `type1Vector`. You actually initialise it to the size of `type1Vector` and then add the converted elements on top of that.

You can easily use standard algorithms to implement what you want:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

vector<Type2> function1(const vector<Type1>& type1Vector) 
{
    vector<Type2> type2Vector;
    type2Vector.reserve(type1Vector.size());
    std::transform(type1Vector.begin(), type1Vector.end(), std::back_inserter(type2Vector), convertion);
    return type2Vector;
}
```

Comment: Why `std::transform` and not just `std::copy`?